# Who to get the text from ckeditor with visual basic

Tags: html, vb.net, editor, ckeditor

I have a problem with the ckeditor and visual basic (using visual studio). I have an .html page with the scrip for use ckeditor, this part is ok, I use a webbrowser for navigate to the web, and can set text with the DocumentCompleted event.

The problem is the reverse, I do not know how to get the text from the ckeditor to a string for example. I know that ckeditor have a function called getdata() ? but I can not called from visual studio (or I do not know how). Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Use [HtmlDocument.InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be9zzz62.aspx) to call `CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstanceName.getData()` in JavaScript. There's an example in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out my friend:

```
Protected Sub btnShowText_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Dim text As String = CKEditor1.Text
  lblText1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(text)
  lblText2.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(text)
End Sub
```

Source: http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/1438.html